# How to get tool tip text using selenium web driver

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to get tool tip text of image and wanted to store in variable. Below is the HTML Code.script is able to perform the mouse hover event and showing the tool tip text value .but unable to get tool tip text value.Please help me on this.

```
<img onmouseover="var relNo=getReleaseNo(); this.T_ABOVE = false; this.T_OFFSETY=-10; this.T_OFFSETX=10; this.T_WIDTH=200; this.T_DELAY=1000; return escape('&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td align=center&gt;Welcome to the Daimler EngineeringPortal&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;' + relNo + '&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;');" src="./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg">
```

PFA Below mentioned is selenium scripts. In script all thing is working exppect unable to get the text.
**Selenium Script**

```
package All_Module_Engp;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Engp_Module {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        File pathToBinary = new File("C:/Users/rrimjhi/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
        driver.get("https://tindito.COM");
            driver.findElement(By.id("usr")).sendKeys("xyz123");
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xyz123");
            driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
//          String s = driver.getTitle();

//          System.out.println(s);
            Actions tooltip = new Actions(driver);
            driver.switchTo().frame("header");
            WebElement img1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg']"));
            tooltip.clickAndHold(img1).perform();

             String ToolTipText = img1.getText();

            System.out.println(ToolTipText);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement elementWithTooltip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(elementWithTooltip).build().perform();
//try to find this tool tip element and verify the text
WebElement tooltip = driver.findElement(By.id("tooltip"));
assertEquals("tooltip content", tooltip.getText());
```

Comment: Actions tooltip = new Actions(driver);
   driver.switchTo().frame("header");
   WebElement  img1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg']"));
   tooltip.clickAndHold(img1).perform();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: If u see the below  html code complete java script there and only i can find the image source and hover the mouse ,i am not able to understand how i get the text.

Comment: <img onmouseover="var relNo=getReleaseNo(); this.T_ABOVE = false; this.T_OFFSETY=-10; this.T_OFFSETX=10; this.T_WIDTH=200; this.T_DELAY=1000; return escape('&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td align=center&gt;Welcome to the Daimler EngineeringPortal&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;' + relNo + '&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;');" src="./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg">

Comment: Can you debug and see what is this statement returning for you System.out.println("text" + driver.findElement[By.cssSelector="img[src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg']"]).getText());

Comment: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (9e7140aa-ed96-4bb2-9ae8-6444aad2044d)] -> xpath: //img[@src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg']]
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //img[src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds

Comment: Used this line of code  System.out.println("text" + driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//img[@src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg']")).getText());

Comment: remove `//` and try..same as in my comment

Comment: System.out.println("text" + driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[@src='./pics/logo/logo_mini.jpg']")).getText());